# Error with bannerslider module on magento 2.1

Tags: magento2.1.0, slider

I've installed the [Magestore Bannerslider v1.8](https://marketplace.magento.com/magestore-bannerslider-magento2.html) on my magento 2.1.0, I've enabled the module, cleared compiled reindexed and everything, and the module is enabled. I created a new slider from the backend, but when I try to go to manage banners, I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Magestore\BannerSlider\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Image' not found in /home/likeeu77/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Any ideea what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you click Content -> Manage Banners you’ll get this exception: `Class Magestore\BannerSlider\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Image` does not exist

This is triggered by some sloppy coding that has uppercase BannerSlider mixed up with lowercase Bannerslider. So to solve it you would need to replace all occurrences of BannerSlider to Bannerslider.

This is pretty easy on linux. All you need to do is this:

Login to your system using SSH

go to `/app/code/Magestore/Bannerslider` path directory

then run this command: sudo find `./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/BannerSlider/Bannerslider/' {} \;`

I hope it will work

http://tdmts.net/2017/03/20/solving-bannerslider-class-magestorebannerslideruicomponentlistingcolumnimage-does-not-exist/#comment-20